# (Asp.net) I can't Insert a new row using Linq to Sql

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

So I'm trying to do a simple insert using Linq but i'm running into trouble.

code:

```
        TestDatacontext db = new TestDatacontext ();
        Comment com = new Comment();
        com.UserID = userId;
        com.TaskID = taskId;
        com.Description = Server.HtmlEncode(txtComments.Text);
        com.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
```

Now at this point, from what I've read I should be able to do this:

```
db.Comments.Add(com);
db.Submitchanges();
```

However, when I write `db.Comments`. [There is no Add method]

So...how do I insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `db.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(com);`

Comment: Thansk man!  Why did I keep seeing db.Comments.Add(com);  I saw it on ScottGu's blog and others.

Comment: Well if you had a parent object Entity that had children Comments, then you would do `myEntity.Comments.Add(com); db.Entities.InsertOnSubmit(myEntity);`, I believe.